SQL Server pivoting on data without an aggregate
I know there are lots of existing questions about pivots, but I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong.
Given this data:
CREATE TABLE #Charges 
(
    name VARCHAR(50),
    Charge DECIMAL(10, 6),
    MinVal DECIMAL(10, 2),
    MaxVal DECIMAL(10, 2)
);

INSERT INTO #Charges (name, Charge, MinVal, MaxVal) 
VALUES ('Foo', 0.500000, 50.00, 500.00),
       ('Foo', 1.000000, 50.00, 500.00),
       ('Foo', 1.500000, 50.00, 500.00),
       ('Foo', 1.750000, 50.00, 500.00)

(in reality this is coming from a sub-query, so these values are not fixed, although name, minVal and maxVal should all be the same. There need to be ten "charge" columns in the output, although there may be less than ten in the result set I'm pivoting)
I'm trying to get this output:
Foo    50.00    500.00    0.500000    1.000000    1.500000    1.750000     

I've tried to make a pivot, but I can't even get the syntax right for the multiple columns needed as part of the FOR IN construct.

You have to know for sure how many columns you'll need (how many Foo rows you'll have) before you can pivot. You will not be able to do this in one step if you don't know this ahead of time. You'll have to use a separate statement to find out how many columns first, and then use that to build dynamic sql.

@JoelCoehoorn I need ten "charge" columns in the output, although there may be less than ten in the result set. I've tried to edit to make this clear

The rule of thumb is, if you can't make the syntax, you're not ready for the pivot operator. Try using conditional aggregation instead which is far more easier (although copypastier)

If you need ten columns, then add a row_number() projection to use as the pivot value, for columns 1..10.

This question is similar to: Group by column and merge multiple rows into one row with multiple columns. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Are MinVal and MaxVal the same for every row of a given name? If so, you should include that case in your sample data and desired results. If they can be different, you should include cases where the min of minval and max of maxval are on different rows, so we can understand exactly the output you want.

You can always take MAX() as a dummy aggregate when the values are unique.

Assuming SQL Server 2022, you can derive the 10 columns from GENERATE_SERIES - cross apply to that and then pivot:
WITH x AS
  (
    SELECT name, Charge, MinVal, MaxVal, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
             (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY @@SPID)
      FROM #Charges
  )
SELECT name, MinVal, MaxVal, 
       [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]
FROM x 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT value FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,10)) AS n(n)
PIVOT (MAX(x.Charge) 
FOR x.rn IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])) AS p
WHERE p.n = 1;


db<>fiddle

If you're on an older version, you can substitute...
CROSS APPLY 
  (SELECT value FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,10)) AS n(n)

...with...
CROSS APPLY 
  (SELECT TOP (10) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
  FROM sys.columns ORDER BY name) AS n(n)


db<>fiddle

In either case, this is a little tidier than conditional aggregation IMHO; however, it assumes than MinVal and MaxVal are constant for all rows of a given name.
